# Design Advice required on SharePoint 2010

Tags: security, groups

I am new to SharePoint
I've a requirement to build Sharepoint 2010 Portal with below specs.
There would be 3 user group

A. Marketing
 B. Sales user
 C. Admin

Marketing group will upload docs and sales group would view and download.
There is a one to Many relationship between Sales:Marketing  like Sales Group A should be allowed to view Marketing Group A ,B produced docs only 
All the users are AD users .
Authentication Mode is NTLM ..

My question is what is the best place to create these groups and which is the best way to create this relationship between Sales and Marketing ..

Any advice would be helpful..

Answer (score 3):

A few guidelines/best practices:

- Apply security at the highest level possible; so first set permissions at the site collection level or even the farm. Then set permissions on the site, then, if necessary, set unique permissions on objects (pages, lists, etc.).
- SharePoint security works much like Windows folder security: Children inherit from parents unless you explicitly break that for unique permissions. This can help you map out your permissions:

  - Who needs read access to the entire site collection? Add this AD group to the Visitors at the root.
  - Who needs editor permission to each site? Add this AD group to the site's Members group.
  - Who needs admin to site collection/site level? Add this AD group(s) to the Owners group at site collection or site level.
  - Any unique permissions? Create custom groups if needed.
- Keep security uniform across all sites. When exceptions occur, document them thoroughly.
- Use folders in document libraries; you can apply security to the folder rather than individual docs.
- Assign individuals to AD groups, then apply those groups to the built-in or custom SharePoint groups (Owners, Members, Visitors, etc.).
- For custom groups, start with a built-in group and modify its access levels. Avoid changing existing SP groups. Don't call a custom group by its security purpose, such as "Restricted Contributors"; use its role instead for the name: "Editors".
- Don't forget about navigation. If you assign special security to an object, it might not show in the built-in navigation.
- Get a copy of the book ["Essential SharePoint 2010 Overview, Governance, and Planning" (Addison-Wesley)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321700759). Chapter 8 covers security extremely well.
- Ask questions here :)